# How to input string in generic search bar and obtain resulting URL - C# scraping

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I need to obtain several pages from a website. It's something like, searching X movie on IMDB.com to get information related to said X.

My problems is that, I know only the name of X, not it's link on the webpage I'm using.

> Note. The site I'm requested to use, sadly doesn't have an api...

I have no idea how to access the search bar, input a string, hit enter and obtain the resulting URL. Any suggestions?

Bonus question, I'm currently using HtmlAgilityPack, it gets the job done but does somebody has any alternatives/recommendations?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be better not to download the HTML of IMDB pages, but use their API.
It should be easier to use. You can find it here: https://developer.imdb.com/

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't  clear enough. I was just using IMDB as an example. The website I need to use doesn't have an API...